# MongoDB : Update statement help, add a counter equal to length of an array in object?

Tags: mongodb

This is the object:

```
{ "_id" : "c12345", 
  "arr" : [
        {
                "i" : 270099850,
                "a" : 772,

        },
        {
                "i" : 286855630,
                "a" : 622,

        }
] }
```

This is the statement that adds one more element to "arr":

```
db.testc.update({"_id" : "c12345"},{$pushAll:{"f":[{"i":123,"a":456456}]},   {"safe":false,"upsert" : true}}
```

**THE MAIN REQUIREMENT IS :** 
**I want one statement like :**

```
 db.testc.update({"_id" : "c12345"},{$pushAll:{"f":[{"i":123,"a":456456}]},
             $set:{"n":"this.f.lenth" }, {"safe":false,"upsert":true})
```

Which will add or modify a key "n" and put an integer as value which equals length of arr .
I want to do it in same statement i.e. without doing a find .

The statement should ideally update it to final length of the "arr" ( or even initial would work by adding 1 to it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't write something like `this.f.length`.

<strike>{ "$pushAll" : { "f" : [{ "i" : 123, "a" : 456456 }] }, "$set" : { "n" : 2 } }</strike>

You can use [$inc](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24inc) to increment `n` (increament value should be equal pushed array length) on each update:

```
{ "$pushAll" : { "f" : [{ "i" : 123, "a" : 456456 }] }, "$inc" : { "n" : 1 } }
```

No need to use `find`.

Comment: Hi Bugai,I ideally wanted the counter to be independent of any operations, my current operation should set it to current length of arr, not by incrementing a counter, or decrementing it when i pop something from "arr", just direct assigning of length. and for first solution,How can I find current length without using find before ?

Comment: You can't get array length before update in language you use and than use $inc? Like *array.Length* in javascript, or *array.Length* in c#.

Comment: @bugai for that i will have to use a find which i do not want as overhead.

Comment: DhruvPathak: I still can't undestand why you need use *find*, mb i've missed something? Can you explain?

Comment: @bugai, perhaps u might hv missed the fact that the record already exists in the mongodb, so how can I get the length of "arr" in it without using "find" first, and checking for size of "arr" in script.

Comment: @DhruvPathak: Ohh, now i see what are you thinking about. So you no need know entire array size, just need to know size of array that you trying to push and increment *n* to this value.. If array *f* is not present *n* value is equal 0, than once you push array with two items into *f* you increment *n* to 2, next time when you push array you againg increment n on pushed array size...